# Создание почты в MS Exchange через Oracle или Java

Tags: java, oracle, exchange

Как создать mailbox (почтовый ящик) в MS Exchange через Oracle PL/SQL или java (прикрепить в oracle)?
Искал везде, есть апи для создания письма и тд.. Но как почтовый ящик создать не могу найти.

Comment: в MS Exchange вроде можно через powershel создавать почтовый ящик.. Тогда вопрос - как вызвать cmdlet через pl/sql

Comment: Вам однозначно нужна внешняя программа, которая обладает нужным вам функционалом и умеющая по параметру переданным в командной строке создавать ящик. PL/SQL Просто должен стартовать ее.

Answer (score 3):

С проблемой разобрался.
На стороне Exchange добавили веб-сервис, который запускает небольшой powershell-скрипт для создания почтового ящика.
На стороне Oracle я вызываю веб-сервис.